# How to integrate HAL (Hypertext Application Language) libraries like "halarious" library with retrofit library?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm working with an api that uses [HAL (Hypertext Application Language)](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and in some responses it includes fields like

```
"_links": {
    "self": { "href": "/account" },
    "numbers": { "href": "/numbers" },
    "menus": { "href": "/menus" },
    "applications": { "href": "/applications" },
    "messages": { "href": "/messages" }
},
```

that is a part of hal. I had searched and found [halarious](http://confluence.surech.ch/display/HAL/halarious+Home?from=DIAp) library and trying to integrate it with my retrofit api. The POJO that is converted is:

```
public class User {
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
    @HalLink
    private String links;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String mRemoteId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String mName;
}
```

and the gson and retrofit config is:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new HalDeserializer(AccountResponse.class))
 .create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new UsersConverter())
            .build();
```

I want to know what should i do next to have this work?

Comment: Creating a new Converter isn't that difficult, just look at the current code for the `GsonConverter` here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.0.1/retrofit/converter/GsonConverter.java

Comment: I used Halarious with Retrofit, you can see my code along with a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404734/