# Multiple converters with Retrofit 2

Tags: java, generics, gson, retrofit, hateoas

I have a [HATEOAS (HAL)](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) REST service and managed to talk to it with the code below (using [halarious](http://confluence.surech.ch/display/HAL/halarious+Home?from=DIAp) as a conversion engine) but when I try to [merge the converters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIAoQbAu3eA&t=19m45s) (`stallone` and `stallone2`), the app will always pick up the first converter, instead of the one that is appropriate for the response type which of course leads to an error.

**How could I avoid duplicate retrofits that are only different in a small type detail?**

```java
public interface Stallone {
   @GET("/discovery")
   Call<DiscoveryResponse> discover();
   @POST()
   Call<LoginResponse> login(@Url String url, @Body LoginRequest secret);
}
```

```java
   public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
      // Initialize a converter for each supported (return) type
      final Stallone stallone = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(BASE)
         .addConverterFactory(HALConverterFactory.create(DiscoveryResponse.class))
         .build().create(Stallone.class);
      final Stallone stallone2 = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(BASE)
         .addConverterFactory(HALConverterFactory.create(LoginResponse.class))
         .build().create(Stallone.class);

      // Follow the HAL links
      Response<DiscoveryResponse> response = stallone.discover().execute();
      System.out.println(response.code() + " " + response.message());
      Assert.assertNotNull(response.body());
      String loginPath = response.body().getLogin();
      Assert.assertEquals(loginPath, "/login");

      // Follow another link
      if (loginPath.startsWith("/"))
         loginPath = loginPath.substring(1);
      Response<LoginResponse> response2 =
         stallone2.login(loginPath,
                        new LoginRequest(AUTH0TOKEN, null)).execute();
      System.out.println(response2.code() + " " + response2.message());
      Assert.assertNotNull(response2.body());

      String setupPath = response2.body().getSetup();
      Assert.assertEquals(setupPath, "/setup");

      System.out.println("All OK!");
   }
```

```java
public final class HALConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

   private final Gson gson;

   public static HALConverterFactory create(Class<?> type) {
      return new HALConverterFactory(type);
   }

   private HALConverterFactory(Class<?> type) {
      if (!HalResource.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
         throw new NullPointerException("Type should be a subclass of HalResource");
      GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
      builder.registerTypeAdapter(HalResource.class, new HalSerializer());
      builder.registerTypeAdapter(HalResource.class, new HalDeserializer(type));
      builder.setExclusionStrategies(new HalExclusionStrategy());
      this.gson = builder.create();
   }

   @Override
   public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> fromResponseBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
      return new HALResponseBodyConverter<>(gson);
   }

   @Override public Converter<?, RequestBody> toRequestBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
      return new GsonRequestBodyConverter<>(gson, type);
   }
}
```

```java
final class HALResponseBodyConverter<T extends HalResource>
   implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
   private final Gson gson;

   HALResponseBodyConverter(Gson gson) {
      this.gson = gson;
   }

   @Override public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
      BufferedSource source = value.source();
      try {
         String s = source.readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
         return (T) gson.fromJson(s, HalResource.class);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } finally {
         closeQuietly(source);
      }
   }

   private static void closeQuietly(Closeable closeable) {
      if (closeable == null) return;
      try {
         closeable.close();
      } catch (IOException ignored) {
      }
   }
}
```

**Again, the problem is that** when you try to shorten the above like this:

```java
  final Stallone stallone = new Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl(BASE)
.addConverterFactory(HALConverterFactory.create(DiscoveryResponse.class))
     .addConverterFactory(HALConverterFactory.create(LoginResponse.class))
     .build().create(Stallone.class);
```

you'll get an exception at the `Response<LoginResponse> response2 = ...` line:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.retrofit.DiscoveryResponse
>   cannot be cast to com.example.retrofit.LoginResponse

Comment: What's `GsonRequestBodyConverter`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to return `null` from the `Converter.Factory` if the type does not match. Keep the `Class<?>` around in a field to compare it against.

```
@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> fromResponseBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
  if (!this.type.equals(type)) {
    return null;
  }
  return new HALResponseBodyConverter<>(gson);
}
```

This will allow multiple instances to be used because each only applies to its own type.

That said, however, you can probably get away with only using a single converter and pulling the class from the `Type` that is passed in.

```
@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> fromResponseBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
  if (!HALResponse.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
    return null;
  }
  // TODO create converter with `type` now that you know what it is...
}
```

You can look at the Wire converter in the repo which does this for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

```
package ch.halarious.core;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Custom Hal Deserializer  
 *
 * @author jaren
 */
public class CustomHalDeserializer extends HalDeserializer {

    /**
     * Intialisiert ein HalDeserializer-Objekt
     *
     * @param targetType Typ, den wir eigentlich deserialisieren sollten
     */
    public CustomHalDeserializer(Class<?> targetType) {
        super(targetType);
    }

    class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList implements HalResource{}

    public HalResource deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context, Class<?> targetType) throws JsonParseException {
        // Es handelt sich um ein JSON-Objekt.
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject embeddedRoot = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject(HalConstants.EMBEDDED_ROOT);

        if(embeddedRoot != null){
            Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = embeddedRoot.entrySet();
            if(set.toArray().length == 1){
                JsonArray ja = embeddedRoot.getAsJsonArray(set.iterator().next().getKey());
                if(ja.isJsonArray()) {
                    CustomArrayList arrayResult = new CustomArrayList();
                    Iterator<JsonElement> i = ja.iterator();
                    while(i.hasNext()){
                        JsonElement je = i.next();
                        arrayResult.add(super.deserialize(je, typeOfT, context, targetType));
                    }
                    return arrayResult;
                }
            }
        }

        return super.deserialize(json, typeOfT, context, targetType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did almost the same as @jake-wharton said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33459073/2055854 but added some changes:

```
public class GenericConverterFactory<T> extends Converter.Factory {

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public static GenericConverterFactory create(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new GenericConverterFactory(clazz);
    }

    private GenericConverterFactory(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (!isNeededType(type)) {
            return null;
        }

        // some converter that knows how to return your specific type T
        return new GenericConverter(clazz);
    }

    private boolean isNeededType(Type type) {
        if(type instanceof GenericArrayType) {
            // if type is array we should check if it has the same component as our factory clazz
            // if our factory clazz is not array getComponentType will return null
            return ((GenericArrayType) type).getGenericComponentType().equals(clazz.getComponentType());
        } else if(clazz.getComponentType() == null) {
            // if factory clazz is not array and type is not array too
            // type is just a Class<?> and we should check if they are equal
            return clazz.equals(type);
        } else {
            // otherwise our clazz is array and type is not
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Type is coming from retrofit interface for example if you have:

```
public interface SomeApi{
     @GET("customelement")
     CustomElement[] getCustomElements();
     @GET("customelement/{id}")
     CustomElement getCustomElement(@Path("id") int id);
}
```

For method `getCustomElements()` type will be `GenericArrayType` with `GenericComponentType` as `CustomElement.class` and for second method type will be just `CustomElement.class`

Not sure whether it is the best solution but for me it works. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to serialize and deserialize only one class to XML. For everything else I needed Json. So I registered my adapters like this:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(EditUserXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(createGson()))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
```

since I could not extend `SimpleXmlConverterFactory` (unfortunately) I had to use my own class and change the following line:

```
if (!(type instanceof Class)) return null;
```

to

```
if (type != NeedToBeXML.class) return null;
```

This way only responses and requests of type `NeedToBeXML` are converted to XML - and everything else JSON.

Comment: Where can I find EditUserXmlConverterFactory?

Comment: Also, where to write this: if (type != NeedToBeXML.class) return null; ?